# Does changing URL in JavaScript prevent Greasemonkey from closing windows?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a greasemonkey script for a web page that redirects to a desktop application. The web page's script does a `window.location.href = 'app_protocol:///url.code'` to trigger the app to open before the Greasemonkey user script runs.

My greasemonkey script correctly detects the web page and then attempts to call `window.close()` but Firefox reports that a script can only close its own window and thus remains open.

So my question is: did the `window.location.href` setting effectively cause Firefox to think it was now a new page and thus my GM script lost the ability to close the window? If so, how can you cause the redirect and still close your window?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just can't call `window.close()` on windows you haven't opened yourself, with a `window.open()`

Comment: @Cerbrus - that is true, but the GM script injection does allow you to close your current window/tab because it injected as part of that window's "self" if you will. Works in other scripts I've made; automate a click of a button on the page, then call window.close and its all good. However, this page modifies the href first before my GM script can run, and thats why I'm thinking it gets blocked.

Comment: Try: 1. `// @grant window.close` 2. Including the URL you are redirecting to in a `@match`.

Comment: @double-beep - I do have the match/include and the grant statement. Issue is that Greasemonkey won't close the window. However, Tampermonkey will do it with those bits. Question was if the page's script changing the HREF causes GM to "lock down" if you will.

Comment: Does the issue happen with Greasemonkey 4 or 3?

Comment: @double-beep GM4.

Comment: Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2538). `// @grant window.close` isn't supported in Greasemonkey. See also: [`@grant` parser](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/11e340b4dadee868191e72a3ef888f75c6eabbc1/src/parse-user-script.js#L112), [`SUPPORTED_APIS`](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/11e340b4dadee868191e72a3ef888f75c6eabbc1/src/supported-apis.js#L2-L10). You should probably switch to Tampermonkey as [the maintainers themselves suggest](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html);

Comment: @double-beep - yeah, that's understood. If seems that if your user script doesn't fuss around with redirections and such, you can close a window in GM4 (I have a use case where GM4 will close the window). So going back to the original question, is what is triggering the lockdown (if you will), the fact that the href/location is getting fiddled with?

Comment: Yes, that's what the issue mentions.